# How can I see CPU and Memory using by any specific mysql query?

Tags: mysql, linux

If I run **top** command on linux,I can see CPU and Memory using by any process. Like that I want to see this in mysql.
If I run **mysql>show processlist**, It gives me **Id,User,Host,db,Command,Time,State,Info** etc values.
But not giving CPU or memory information.
How can I get this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linux perf command (from linux-tools-common package).

For example, for your command:

```
$ perf stat <your command>
```

For your process:

```
$ perf top
```

There are many options besides the above for your needs.

You can refer website: http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

Answer (score -1):

you return memory usage by mysql query:

`mysql> SELECT MEMORY_PEAK as memory;`

for checking CPU footprint you can use:

`root@database:/home/user# vmstat 1 10`

in your linux command